# How to make setup.py for standalone python application in a right way?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have read several similar topics but haven't succeeded yet. I feel I miss or misunderstand some fundamental thing and this is the reason of my failure.
I have an 'application' written in a python which I want to deploy with help of standard setup.py. Due to complex functionality it consists of different python modules. But there is no sense in separate release of this modules as they are too specific.
Expected result is to have package installed in a system with help of `pip install` and be available from OS command line with simple `app` command.
Simplifying long story to reproducible example - I have following directory structure:

```
<root>
  ├─ app
  |   ├─ aaa
  |   |   └── module_a.py
  |   ├─ bbb
  |   |   └── module_b.py
  |   └── app.py
  ├─ docs
  |   └── .....
  ├─ tests
  |   └── .....
  └─ setup.py
```

Below is code of modules:
**app.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from aaa.module_a import method1
from bbb.module_b import method2

def main():
    print("APP main executed")
    method1()
    method2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**module_a.py**

```
def method1():
    print("A1 executed")
```

**module_b.py**

```
def method2():
    print("B2 executed")
```

When I run *app.py* from console it works fine and gives expected output:

```
APP main executed
A1 executed
B2 executed
```

So, this simple 'application' works fine and I want to distribute it with help of following
**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="app",
    version="1.0",
    packages=['app', 'app.aaa', 'app.bbb'],
    package_dir={'app': 'app'},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['app=app.app:main', ]
    }
)
```

Again, everything looks good and test installation looks good:

```
(venv) [user@test]$ pip install <root>
Processing /home/user/<root>
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for app, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: app
    Running setup.py install for app ... done
Successfully installed app-1.0
(venv) [user@test]$
```

And now comes the problem. With aforementioned *entry_points* from setup.py I expect to be able execute my application with *./app* command. Indeed it works. But application itself fails with error message:

```
File "/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from aaa.module_a import method1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aaa'
```

I understand the reason of the error - it is because `pip install` put directories `aaa` and `bbb` together with `app.py` in one directory `app`. I.e. from this point of view `app.py` should use `import app.aaa` instead of `import aaa`. But if I do so then my app during development runs with error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.aaa'; 'app' is not a package
```

that is also logical as there are no `app` package available at that time... (it is under development and isn't installed in the system...)

Finally. The question is - what is a correct way to create directory structure and setup.py for standalone python application that consist of several own modules?

**UPD**
The most promising result (but proved to be wrong after discussion in coments) that I have now came after following changes:

1. moved app.py from `<root>/app` into `<root>` itself
2. I referenced it in `setup.py` by `py_modules=['app']`
3. I changed imports from `import aaa.method1` to `import app.aaa.method1` etc.

This way package works both in my development environment and after installation.
But I got a problem with `entry_points` - I see no way how to configure entry point to use `main()` from `app.py` that is not a part of `app` package but is a separate module....
I.e. new structure is

```
<root>
  ├─ app
  |   ├─ aaa
  |   |   └── module_a.py
  |   ├─ bbb
  |   |   └── module_b.py
  |   └──__init__.py
  ├─ docs
  |   └── .....
  ├─ tests
  |   └── .....
  ├─ app.py
  └─ setup.py
```

I.e. the logic here - to have 2 separate entities:

1. An empty package `app` (consists of **init**.py only) with subpackages `aaa`, `bbb` etc.
2. A script `app.py` that uses functions from subpackages `app.aaa`, `app.bbb`

But as I wrote - I see no way how to define entry point for `app.py` to allow it's run from OS command line directly.

Comment: Looks like you don't need the `package_dir` parameter in your `setup.py`. Don't think it will fix anything, but still. -- You say you call the application with `./app`, that seems strange to me. There should not be any `app` executable in the current directory. But you should be able to call `app` directly though. -- Indeed the imports seem wrong. Maybe look at this: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/python_imports.html

Comment: I tried to remove `package_dir` - nothing have changed.

Comment: And sorry for confusion with `./app` and `app`. I'm calling it as `app` after installation as it is referenced in `entry_points` but when I'm in development environment - I'm running it from IDE or directly from command line as `./app.py` in right directory

Comment: Regarding your newest edit: you definitely can not have both a top level package named `app` and a top level module named `app`. I do not see how that could possibly work. Even if it did work, I would not recommend this.

Comment: Actually it works and seems to be a good way forward as it separates topic into empty package `app`(this is why I added `__init__.py` there) with sub-packages `app.aaa`, `app.bbb` and a single module `app.py` that imports and uses these sub-packages. So, it has a logic behind and I don't see a contradiction. I just see no way how to setup an entry_point for a single python file that is not a part of package (syntax of a command requires package name....)

Comment: For a console script entry point that points at a function from a top level module: `app:main`.

Comment: I tried it... `entry_points={ 'console_scripts': ['app:main', ] }` gives an erorr `error in app setup command: ("EntryPoint must be in 'name=module:attrs [extras]' format", 'app:main')`

Comment: Obviously `app=app:main`. But honestly, since you now seem to insist on wanting to have both a top level `app` module and package, I have no clue what will happen.

Comment: 1) No, I don't insist to have both on top level. 2) `app=app:main` is obvius but it doesn't work (it doesn't work at all if `app.py` is at top level and if `app.py` is inside `app` because in this case correct form is `app=app.app:main`. 3) Ok, let's come back to initial setup when `app.py` is inside `app` directory. This way installation works fine. But as I wrote below  - it gives an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.aaa'; 'app' is not a package` in development environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that directory (package) structure, in your `app.py` you should import as one of the following:

```py
from app.aaa.module_a import method1
```

```py
from .aaa.module_a import method1
```

Then make sure to call you application like one of the following:

```
app
```

(this should work thanks to the console entry point)

```
python -m app.app
```

(this should work even without the console entry point)

---

***I try to recreate the complete project here***

Directory structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── aaa
│   │   └── module_a.py
│   ├── app.py
│   └── bbb
│       └── module_b.py
└── setup.py
```

`setup.py`

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="app",
    version="1.0",
    packages=['app', 'app.aaa', 'app.bbb'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['app=app.app:main', ]
    },
)
```

`app/app.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from .aaa.module_a import method1
from .bbb.module_b import method2

def main():
    print("APP main executed")
    method1()
    method2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`app/aaa/module_a.py`

```py
def method1():
    print("A1 executed")
```

`app/bbb/module_b.py`

```py
def method2():
    print("B2 executed")
```

Then I run following commands:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.9
```

```
$ python3 -m venv .venv
```

```
$ .venv/bin/python -m pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
# [...]
```

```
$ .venv/bin/python -m pip list
Package       Version
------------- -------------------
pip           20.3.3
pkg-resources 0.0.0
setuptools    51.1.0.post20201221
wheel         0.36.2
```

```
$ .venv/bin/python -m pip install .
# [...]
```

```
$ .venv/bin/python -m app.app
APP main executed
A1 executed
B2 executed
```

```
$ .venv/bin/app
APP main executed
A1 executed
B2 executed
```

```
$ .venv/bin/python -m pip uninstall app
# [...]
```

```
$ .venv/bin/python -m pip install --editable .
# [...]
```

```
$ .venv/bin/python -m app.app
APP main executed
A1 executed
B2 executed
```

```
$ .venv/bin/app
APP main executed
A1 executed
B2 executed
```

Comment: As I wrote - if I make  `from app.aaa.module_a import method1` then it results into an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.aaa'; 'app' is not a package`

Comment: From what I can see `app` is definitely a top level package of the project, so it should work. After installing this project it should definitely be possible to `import app`, if not, then something else went wrong.

Comment: Yes, it would be possible to make `import app`, you are completely right here. But I don't need it. I need a possibility to run it directly from OS command line. This is the point. And here I have a problem - 1) either I can run it with `app` according to defined entry points but it can't import underlying `app.aaa` or 2) I can't setup a proper entry_points for the separate `app.py` module (see UPD section in question)

Comment: This does not seem normal at all. Are you sure things are being completely uninstalled and then reinstalled correctly? You might want to make sure to delete the `egg-info` directory between install attempts.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that everything was uninstalled. What is not normal from you point of view? Not clear....

Comment: This should work. There is nothing unusual about your setup or your project directory structure that I can see. It seems all pretty straightforward.

Comment: I gave you all the info. You may try it your self - it doesn't work for both cases simultaneously. It works either after installation or in development environment. But not both at the same time, with the same imports and setup.py.

Comment: But the way, I checked your link https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/python_imports.html - in item #3 it says about 2 mandatory conditions - neither of them is satisfied in my case and I can't satisfy 1st as it's development phase, and 2nd because app.py working directory is below app directory, not upper.

Comment: I recreated the full example. Seems to work all fine as expected in my case. Let me know if I forgot something, or if you can spot any difference between your project and mine.

Comment: Hi @sinoroc Thanks for your efforts - from code you shared I see some difference but I need to check it carefully. It is too late today here - I'll do it tomorrow and share results.

Comment: I repeated your example step by step and confirm it works. It seems I understand how it works. But I understand that the main prerequisite to its success is `pip install` - i.e. you have installed package before the execution and this way package `app` becomes a known thing. Right? But then I have a question how to debug it? I.e. I'm accustomed to be able to run code at any moment from IDE while I work on it. Does it mean now I need to install it before every test run? Will PyCharm debugger understand it?... I'm not a seasoned python developer but it doesn't sounds like a good way for me...

Comment: Yes, the project has to be installed one way or another. If you want to still make changes to the code then you need the "_editable_" install: `python -m pip install --editable .` (it used to be _setuptools_'s "_develop_" installation `python setup.py develop` but it is now mostly deprecated, better do it via _pip_). This is a special case of installation, it is not "really" installed, and it allows you to keep making changes without having to reinstall after each code change.

Comment: sinoroc, thanks a lot. Discussion with you helped me to understand the situation and fill the gap in my knowledge. `pip install --editable` for sure will do the trick as it keeps source files in place accessible to IDE. It appears I just need to configure `venv` inside PyCharm in a proper way. But also I found and have read `https://packaging.python.org/overview/` - I plan to check PEP 441 and `pex` and `shiv` in order to understand how it applies to my case. Probably it would be worth to mention these stuff in answer section.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from sinoroc is mostly right - he executed a correct example that highlights all options. It shows a correct way to structure python package. But before any run this package should be first installed into venv. Then `pip install --editable` option is required in order to continue develop/debug the package inside IDE (it installs package in venv but keeps source files in original place).

After long discussion in comments I came to the page [An Overview of Packaging for Python](https://packaging.python.org/overview/) that explains all options and highlights that *Python’s native packaging is mostly built for distributing reusable code, called libraries*. I assume this is a reason of my misunderstanding and initial question.

As an alternative solution I plan to play with [PEP 441 -- Improving Python ZIP Application Support](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0441/) that looks like a correct approach for my case.