# Can't import my own module in my test file

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I have the following project structure :

```
.
├── README.md
├── document_processing
│   ├── Config.py
│   ├── DocumentParser.py
│   ├── FileChecker.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── indexing.py
└── tests
    ├── CheckFileTest.py
    └── __init__.py
```

In CheckFileTest.py, I have implemented some tests for the FileChecker.py functions.

```
import unittest
from document_processing.Config import Config
from document_processing.FileChecker import FileChecker

class CheckFileTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = Config()
        self.fc = FileChecker(self.config)
    
    def test_not_empty_line(self):
        ...
        
    def test_line_format(self):
        ...
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Unfortunately, I got this error when I'm trying to run the test file (launched from the project root) :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thomaslaurent/Dev/MIRCV_project/tests/CheckFileTest.py", line 3, in <module>
    from document_processing.Config import Config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'document_processing
```

I have seen many things on that, but I can't figure out what's blocked with this structure.

With relative import :

```
from ..document_processing.Config import Config
```

I got this error :

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

**EDIT**

Following the comments of @sinoroc, I doesn't make tests a package and I have created a setup.py file  :

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="MIRCV_project",
    version="1.0",
    description="",
    author="Thomas LAURENT",
    author_email="",
    packages=["document_processing"],
    install_requires=[],  # external packages acting as dependencies
)
```

And I finally run :

```
python -m pip install --editable .
```

You can go vote for a previous answer of @sinoroc on setup.py configuration :
[How to make setup.py for standalone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65407999/how-to-make-setup-py-for-standalone-python-application-in-a-right-way)

Comment: Is your project correctly installed (installed as editable is fine of course)? -- How do you "_run the test file_"?

Comment: I run the the test file with : python3 tests/CheckFileTest.py or with the run command from vsCode

Comment: Are you sure your project is correctly installed and its packages are importable? What happens when you run something like `python3 -c 'import document_processing; print(document_processing)'`?

Comment: It actually worked and printed : <module 'document_processing' from '/Users/thomaslaurent/Dev/MIRCV_project/document_processing/__init__.py'>

Comment: Then this should work, I do not see any reason why it would not. -- I recommend  you use a test suite runner such as *pytest* (and even though I do not recommend it, you might be able to use *unittest* as test suite runner: `python3 -m unittest`) -- I do not believe you should resort to using relative imports, make any modifications to `sys.path` or the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable as you will see suggested all around the internet. At best those are temporary hacks, but they are not a reliable long-term solution.

Comment: @Atro_TLT I agree with everything sinoroc stated. I think the issue is that you _haven't_ installed your project correctly. Does `python3 -c 'import document_processing; print(document_processing)'` still work if you `cd` into the `tests` directory? It sounds to me like you're implicitly relying on the root directory of your project being added to the import path, but haven't taken steps to make that happen consistently.

Comment: Do you have a `pyproject.toml` or `setup.py` file? If not, create a `pyproject.toml` file, fill in the boilerplate for your build system of choice, then `pip install -e .`. If you set things up correctly, `import document_processing` will work consistently regardless of what file you're running or what your CWD is. See [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) for more details.

Comment: You were right, the command didn't work into the tests directory. I have created the setup.py and installed it. Now the command work but I'm still getting the same error when launching the test file. I will edit my question to show what I have done.

Comment: Unrelated to issue but still important: I recommend you remove `tests` from the `packages` list in `setup.py` (tests are not meant to be installed), and remove `tests/__init__.py` (tests is not meant to be an importable package at all). Also you should always use `python -m pip install .` instead of `python setup.py install`. And finally I recommend to use editable installation while you are still in the development phase: `python -m pip install --editable .`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! With your last advices it works !

Answer (score -2):

Python searches directories relative to the program file it loaded.

If you are running `tests/CheckFileTest.py`, then your effective root directory (for package searching) is `tests/`. That is not the current directory, only the package search root directory.

For `CheckFileTest.py` to import `Config.py` starting from `tests`, it would have to import ../document_processing/Config.py.  It requires searching *up* the directory tree from tests, which Python does not do. If it did it could backtrack all the way to the root directory and end up searching the entire filesystem, which could be incredibly slow. Python only looks *down* the directory tree from a given search root.

There are a few ways you can solve this. The hacky way is to modify the search path to include additional search root directories.

For example, if you want it to search relative to the current directory from which you issued the command (like in your example):

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
from document_processing.Config import Config
from document_processing.FileChecker import FileChecker
```

Or if you might execute the command from anywhere, and really want it to import relative to the installation, you could do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from document_processing.Config import Config
from document_processing.FileChecker import FileChecker
```

But that will *only* work if `document_processing` and `tests` are peers.

A better way is to reorganize your project as a single package, like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── indexing.py
└── tests
    ├── CheckFileTest.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── document_processing
        ├── Config.py
        ├── DocumentParser.py
        ├── FileChecker.py
        └── __init__.py
```

Then the import from CheckFileTest.py will work the way you have it written, no matter what directory you run the program from.

Comment: If the project is installed correctly then `document_processing` is already in one of the directories listed by `sys.path`. There is almost never a good reason to make `sys.path` modifications, if packaging and installation are done correctly.

Comment: -1 for the reasons sinoroc mentioned. Messing with `sys.path` at runtime is a brittle bandaid for a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: The suggestions to make `document_processing` a subpackage of `tests` seems really weird. Could you clarify why you think that would be beneficial?

Comment: The OP asked how to do it. Sys.path may be a hack method (and I clearly labeled it as such), but it is a supported method and deserves to be mentioned.

Comment: @Brian61354270 My purpose here is not to give a lesson on how best to organize this specific project (which may be a straw man for all I know), but to explain how to import without using relative imports. I considered changing the code to make tests a subdirectory, but that made for a longer and more complicated answer. I elected to demonstrate the method, and leave it to the OP how best to organize the project armed with that knowledge.

Answer (score -3):

```
from ..document_processing.Config import Config
from ..document_processing.FileChecker import FileChecker
```

Comment: With your solution, I've got the following error : ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**